# Having problems accessing json output to update jquery function

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion, lucee

This is a bit long. Thank you guys in advance. Am building a live chat app. Am stuck at how to inform the customer that the agent is currently typing a message. I have 3 ColdFusion scripts to do this:

customer.cfm (the customer chat interface)

```
<script src = "jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div align="right" id="agent-typing-indicator" style="display: none;">Agent is typing...</div>

<script>
// other codes here

setInterval(function () {
$.get("notify_typing.cfm", function (data) {
    // Update the isTyping status in customer.cfm based on the response
    var isTyping = data.isTyping;
    agentIsTyping(isTyping);
}); }, 5000); // Check every 5 seconds


function agentIsTyping(isTyping) {
if (isTyping) {
    // Show a message or indicator to the customer to indicate that the agent is typing.
    $("#agent-typing-indicator").show();
} else {
    // Hide the typing indicator when the agent stops typing.
    $("#agent-typing-indicator").hide();
}
}
</script>
```

agent.cfm (the agent chat interface)

```
<script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script> // other codes here

// Detect typing start and stop in the input field
var typingTimer; // Timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 1000; // Time in milliseconds, e.g., 1000 ms = 1 second
$("#agent-response").on("keyup", function () {
clearTimeout(typingTimer);
// Start a timer to detect when the agent stops typing
typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
// Notify the client that the agent is typing
notifyClientOfTyping(true);
});

$("#agent-response").on("keydown", function () {
// Clear the timer, indicating the agent is still typing
clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

function doneTyping() {
// Agent stopped typing, notify the client
notifyClientOfTyping(false);
}

function notifyClientOfTyping(isTyping) {
$.post("notify_typing.cfm", { isTyping: isTyping }, function (data) {
    // Handle the response if needed
    console.log(data);
});
}
</script>
```

notify_typing.cfm

(receives the agent typing status from agent.cfm via ajax post and feeds the same agent typing status via ajax get to customer.cfm)

```
<cfparam name="form.isTyping" default="">
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "isTyping")>
<cfset isTyping = form.isTyping>
<cfcontent type="application/json">
 <cfoutput>{"isTyping": #serializeJSON(isTyping)#}</cfoutput>  
</cfif>
```

I have used [ console.log(data); ] to confirm that agent.cfm is sending the correct json values, either {isTyping: 'true'} or {isTyping: 'false'}, to notify_typing.cfm.

The problem is that i receive empty json values ( {isTyping: ''} ) from notify_typing.cfm when customer.cfm makes a json call ( i used console.log(data); to confirm this in customer.cfm ). Hence, am unable to hide or show the 'Agent is typing...' in the customer.cfm. Please help.

I have tried for more than 5 days to solve this without any headway.

Comment: It will be empty because the var in the cfm form scope you are referring to is empty. CFdump the form scope to see what data is passed. Then use this var. Would probably look at websockets though as you will struggle with an implementation like this.

Comment: You should use websockets for live chat including "is typing" functionality. The ajax approach is much more difficult. You need a Node server to handle the chat and authenticate the connection using authentication cookies sent from the CF application. And don't use `cfwebsocket`, you need something more flexible. Example of the NodeJS code:  https://dev.to/devland/build-a-real-time-chat-app-using-nodejs-and-websocket-441g